# Multipart File Upload - Do not allow certain file types or just allow PDFs to be uploaded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have an endpoint for uploading files -

```
public ResponseEntity<?> saveFile(@RequestParam("parentCollection") String parentCollection,
        @RequestParam("targetCollectionName") String targetCollectionName,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        //Method for handling
}
```

However, I want to limit the filetypes that can be uploaded. Is there an annotation way to check the content types of the Multipart file that is being uploaded and reject it if its not in one of the allowed file types ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/pdf")
```

Comment: I have to take in 2 other parameters in the form as well as check with a list of allowable file formats ? 

Do u suggest creating a model for the file along with the other 2 parameters and then having a validator ?